# Closest Point to Moving Target

Tags: algorithms, efficiency, speed

I have a target which is constantly moving, and only its current position is ever known.  I also have about one hundred objects surrounding it, and for each of these only the current position is known.

I am trying to find a more efficient way to find the closest object to my target at any given moment in time.  I have looked at a bunch of algorithms, but none of them seem to fit this (nearest neighbor, closest pair of points, etc.).

My objects are unsorted.  It does **not** need to be exact.  The closest I have been able to think of is the brute force algorithm:

```
Objects objects = MyListOfUnsortedObjects();
Object closestObj = objects[0];
for each (Object obj in objects){
    if(obj is closer than closestObj){
        closestObj = obj;
    }
}
return closestObj;
```

Obviously, this is terribly inefficient.  Would I be better off sorting and then dividing and conquering?  Or am I way off base?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may find [Chases and Escapes: The Mathematics of Pursuit and Evasion](http://www.amazon.com/Chases-Escapes-Mathematics-Princeton-Puzzlers/dp/0691155011) something to read tangential to this problem.

Comment: @MichaelT your treat? :-p thanks for the reference. maybe one day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is some form of [**spatial partitioning**](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/spatial-partition.html), which is arguably equivalent to "sort it and then divide and conquer", so you're not off-base at all.

There are many data structures used for this, such as quadtrees, BSPs, k-d trees, and so on. In my personal experience people normally recommend the quadtree as a good starting point.

Comment: Awesome thanks!  And that resource looks great!  Pictures and everything!

Comment: You're very welcome. =) There's also loads of far more detailed Q&As about this stuff under [the collision-detection tag at gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collision-detection)